# How to avoid the hidden files on the hard drive being displayed in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I was using chrome as pdf viewer as it displays more clear than the system viewer. But there are many folders in Home dir. When I enter the home dir into address bar, I have to spend a lot of time (or Ctrl+F) to find the dir I want to go in.

How to avoid the hidden files (file name started with `.`) on the disk being displayed in chrome when browsing files on the disk using chrome?

[image]

Comment: What are you doing exactly ?

Comment: @SorenA I was using chrome as pdf viewer as it displays more clear than the system viewer. But there are many folders in Home dir. When I enter the home dir into address bar, I have to spend a lot of time to find the dir I want to go in.

Comment: @mt1022 how exactly does Chrome provide a clearer view? I don't see anything the file browser cannot show, and the file browser can of course hide .folders

Comment: @muru I think the question is not about the folder view being clearer or not, but the PDFs: *it displays more clear than the system viewer*.

Comment: @CelticWarrior [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Chrome is not intended to be a file browser, Nautilus is. So, instead of hacking our way around it, we should be looking at the root problem - the part you quote to me

Comment: @muru My understanding is the OP uses/prefers Chrome to views PDFs because *it displays* (the PDFs) *more clear then the system viewer* (Evince?). The "file manager inside Chrome" thing is a consequence: OP *enter(s) the home dir into address bar* to looks for their PDFs and question is about how to not show the hidden file/folders in the Chrome's file manager view. So not so much an XY but probably a perception issue (how exactly can a browser be "more clear"?).

Comment: @CelticWarrior in which case the XY problem still persists - what's wrong with the program that's dedicated to viewing documents?

Comment: @muru, sorry about the confusion. I don't knwon th reason but the Domument Viewer displays pdf in a litte blurred manner on my machine. I may ask a seperate question about this. Let's ignore the pdf issue and focus on how to hide the hidden file when broswering files  using chrome here.